# Unable to connect to FTP to append to file genereated form PHP script

Tags: php, xml, ftp

I wrote a PHP script that generates passwords and appendes them to an XML file on another server using FTP. However when I attempt to run the script it will throw errors. Below are the errors im getting. Ive checked the FTP connection and it appears to be funtioning correctly. I can also connect to the FTP on a FTP client.

> Warning: unlink(): Unable to connect to ftp://[redacted for security]/HostSecurity.xml in /path/to/file/public_html/hub/testbed.php on line 52
>
> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::asXML(ftp://[redacted for security]/HostSecurity.xml): failed to open stream: operation failed in /path/to/file/public_html/hub/testbed.php on line 53
>
> Warning: unlink(): Unable to connect to ftp://[redacted for security]/HostSecurity.xml in path/to/file/public_html/hub/testbed.php on line 59
>
> Warning: DOMDocument::save(ftp://[redacted for security]/HostSecurity.xml): failed to open stream: operation failed in path/to/file/public_html/hub/testbed.php on line 60

**PHP SCRIPT**

```
<?php
include_once "includes/jdbh.inc.php";
include_once "includes/dbh.inc.php";
include_once "includes/functions.inc.php";
include_once "includes/ftpconn2.inc.php";
$affectedRow = 0;

error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$fileName = "HostSecurity.xml";
$file = "http://ipaddress to server/HostSecurity.xml";
$ftpUrl = "ftp://$ftp_user:$ftp_password@$ftp_server/$fileName";
$orders = simplexml_load_file($file) or die("Error: Cannot create object");

$userIDs = getUserInfo($jconn);
 foreach ($userIDs as $userId){
    $usersId = $userId['id'];
 
    if (userIdCheck($conn,$usersId) == FALSE) {
            $passwordGen = generateRandomString();
            createServerPassword($conn, $usersId, $passwordGen);
            $loginData = $orders->Unique_Logins;
            $login = $loginData->addChild('UniqueLogin');
            $login->addchild('UID', '');
            $login->addChild('Password', $passwordGen);
            unlink($ftpUrl); //line 52
            $orders->asXML($ftpUrl); //line 53
            $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
            $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
            $dom->formatOutput = true;
            $dom->loadXML($orders->asXML());
            //$dom->loadXML($orders->asXML());
            unlink($ftpUrl); //line 59
            $dom->save($ftpUrl); // line 60
            $affectedRow ++;
        }
    } 
if ($affectedRow > 0) {
    $message = $affectedRow . " records inserted";
}else{
    $message = "No records inserted";
}
?>

<div class="affected-row">
    <?php  echo $message; ?>
</div>
<?php if (! empty($error_message)) { ?>
<div class="error-message">
    <?php echo nl2br($error_message); ?>
</div>
<?php }
```

Comment: You are using a stream wrapper (ftp) and although that is 100% valid and exactly why they exist, it can also make debugging hard. I would personally recommend separating your password stuff from your XML stuff from your FTP stuff. You also appear to be deleting and writing the same file in a tight loop and that could be switched to a single time, probably

Comment: @ChrisHaas I really have no idea where tyo start with that. I've searched the internet extensively but haven't come up with anything worthwhile

Comment: It is way less complicated than you think. Make a chuck of code (function, class, whatever) that does your password stuff. Since you’ve got more than one, store it in an array. Next,  make another chunk of code that acts upon that data and produces XML, probably a local temporary file or string. Lastly, use the [PHP FTP functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ftp-put.php) or a [library](https://packagist.org/packages/nicolab/php-ftp-client) to transfer the file.